# Program Failing to find channel - discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Below is my code on discord.js for sending an embed to the chosen channel in line 21.

Every time I run the slash command my error message shows up in the console. Any help would be amazing.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, Guild, Client,  } = require('discord.js');
const user = require('./user');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds ]});

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('lifetimeupgrade')
        .setDescription('New Lifetime Member')
        .addUserOption(option =>
          option
            .setName('user')
            .setDescription('The member who got Lifetime')
            .setRequired(true))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageGuild),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const messageEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setDescription(`${interaction.user} **HAS UPGRADED TO LIFETIME** :fire: :gem:`)
            .setColor(0xFF0000);
        
        const channelID = '978428599247962126';
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);

        if (channel && channel.isText()) {
            channel.send({ embeds: [messageEmbed] });
        } else {
            console.error('Channel not found or is not a text channel');
        }
    },
};
```

I have tried to add the guild ID into the code but that has not worked, I have tried to get it to send as a reply and that has worked. Not sure why it keeps on failing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not regenerate client. Instead, use `interaction.client`.
This is because the Client you generated in this file is an entirely new Client, and there is no login information, etc

**EDIT:** you can get slash command args through `interaction.options`.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, Guild, Client,  } = require('discord.js');
const user = require('./user');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('lifetimeupgrade')
        .setDescription('New Lifetime Member')
        .addUserOption(option =>
          option
            .setName('user')
            .setDescription('The member who got Lifetime')
            .setRequired(true))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageGuild),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const messageEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setDescription(`${interaction.options.getUser("user")} **HAS UPGRADED TO LIFETIME** :fire: :gem:`)
            .setColor(0xFF0000);
        
        const channelID = '978428599247962126';
        const channel = interaction.client.channels.cache.get(channelId);

        if (channel && channel.isText()) {
            channel.send({ embeds: [messageEmbed] });
        } else {
            console.error('Channel not found or is not a text channel');
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: In like 17 where it says (`${interaction.user} **HAS UPGRADED TO LIFETIME** :fire: :gem:`), I need the embed to have the member of that member i submitted into the command in .addUserOption.

Comment: @tom-andriunas edited!